# Merge only two files from Pull request containing 100 files as changed?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I raised a pull request containing 100 file changes but out of which only 2 files need to be merged into master.

**My question:** Is it possible for the collaborator to merge only those two particular files into master ignoring remaining 98 files? Is that option available on Bitbucket/Git?

Answer (score 3):

If only two files need to be merged a better solution would be for you to push a new commit to the branch reverting the state of the other 98 files.

But to answer your question explicitly, I don't know of anyway to merge a partial PR.

Answer (score 3):

No - a pull request is a single transaction. If merged, it will be all or nothing in regards to your commits. You'll need to separate out the two files you'd like to commit if you want. The good thing is that a PR is actively tracking your updates until it is either closed or merged.

I would push a new commit that removes the files you don't want to include. For example:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
    new file:   one
    new file:   three
    new file:   two

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
    new file:   one
    new file:   three
    new file:   two

$ git commit -m "test"
[master 855ab7c8af51] test
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 one
 create mode 100644 three
 create mode 100644 two

$ git rm one two three
rm 'one'
rm 'three'
rm 'two'
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
Changes to be committed:
    deleted:    one
    deleted:    three
    deleted:    two

$ git commit -m "removing unneeded files"
[master 6957f9b3016b] removing unneeded files
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 one
 delete mode 100644 three
 delete mode 100644 two
$ git push
```

And if you don't like all this mess in your git commit history, you can run an interactive rebase to clean it up: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase-i/